# using the elimination rule in natural deduction

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

Prove that

$$(A ∧ B) \to C ⊢ A \to (B \to C)$$

Am I using the conjuction elimination rule correctly? Or am I assuming too much?

> 1. $(A ∧ B) \to C$  (Given)
> 2. $A \to C , B -> C$ (∧E 1)
> 3. $A \to( B \to C)$ ($\to$I 2) (QED)

Comment: I don't think you can do that. Conjunction elimination gives $A \wedge B \to A$, and you're given $A \wedge B \to C$, but that doesn't mean $A \to C$. For example, if $x \geq 0$ and $x \leq 1$, then $x \in [0,1]$. But obviously just one of those conditions isn't enough for $x$ to be in that interval.

Comment: then I am confused on how to approach this problem

Answer (score 1):

**(1) The Conjunction Elimination Rule**

In a standard natural deduction system, the Conjunction Elimination Rule states that

> $$\frac{\varphi \wedge \psi}{\varphi} \frac{\varphi \wedge \psi}{\psi} \tag{$\wedge$E}$$

Which means we are allowed to apply it in sentences with a conjunction as its logical structure.

But you are **not allowed** to apply this rule in the above case. The sentence you have above is not a conjunction, but an implication. You are **not** using conjunction elimination correctly.

---

**(2) Your Answer**

In order to prove this statement, it suffices to see the logical form of your goal:
$$A \to (B \to C)$$
this suggests that in order to prove  this statement, we first **assume** $A$ as hypothesis, and eventually **assume** $B$ too, in order to obtain C:

> 1. $(A ∧ B) \to C$, P
>
> > 2. $A$, H
> >
> > > 3. $B$, H
> > > 4. $A \wedge B$, 2, 3 $\wedge$I
> > > 5. $C$, 1, 4 $\to$E (Modus Ponens)
> > > 6. $B \to C$, 3-5 $\to$I
> > > 7. $A \to (B \to C)$, 2-6 $\to$I

Keep working!